# Variable autolink object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I have this code in angular

```
$scope.b = {text: "b"};
$scope.a = {};
$scope.a = $scope.b;
$scope.a.text = "a";
console.log($scope.b); // Object {text: "a"};
```

It should be print Object {text: "b"}. I don't want 2 variables link together (when I change a, b should not change)

Comment: If you don't want `$scope.a = $scope.b;` then why do you have that line?

Comment: Because I need copy all value from b -> a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in JavaScript, assign an object means ref to the object.

if you want make `a` and `b` refer to different objects. you should copy that.

angular provides two shortcuts for copy:

**deep copy** [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.a = {};
//angular.copy(source, destination)
angular.copy($scope.b, $scope.a);
```

**shallow copy**  [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
$scope.a = {};
//angular.extend(destination, source1, source2 ...)
angular.extend($scope.a, $scope.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code the same:

```
$scope.a = $scope.b = {};
$scope.a.text = "a" // $scope.a = $scope.b = {text: "a"}
```

Because $scope.a and scope.b have pointer to one Object, so when you change $scope.a the $scope.b will change.

Solution: you can use angular.copy(source, [destination]);
[You can read this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
angular.copy($scope.a, $scope.b);
```